# If condition resolving as true when value is zero

Tags: javascript

My code basically looks like this:

```
console.log(placeCost) //this returns 0 (the number, not string)
 if (!placeCost || placeCost == false || placeCost == "undefined" || placeCost == '') {
 console.log("no")
             }
else {console.log('yes')}
```

Results is "no" in the console. Why does this resolve as "true"?

Comment: because `!` negates a value, so `!0` is true, and since it is true it doesn't need to test the rest of the conditions

Comment: 0 is falsy. use the === operator to check.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I thought that meant that if the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: it does, `!undefined`, `!null`, `!0` all evaluate to true. When testing variable existence you are testing against `undefined`

Comment: @jonmrich if the variable doesnt exist, the engine will crash. If it exists, but is nit defined yet, it is *undefined*

Comment: also: `var a = []; a == !a`. JavaScript is kind of strange in this regard..

Comment: @PatrickEvans I removed the `!placeCost` part and it still returns "no
"

Comment: this is because `placeCost == false` is true for `placeCost = 0`. Use `placeCost === false` to check the type

Comment: @Bellian I changed to `placeCost === false` and same thing

Comment: see answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46001862/3588584

Comment: `placeCost == "undefined"` is comparing the value of `placeCost` the the string `"undefined"`. Remove the quotes to test if the the variable is an undefined variable. `placeCost == undefined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `===` operator and don't check for `!var` if you plan to accept falsy parameters.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

```
if (placeCost === false || placeCost === "undefined" || placeCost === '') {
    console.log("no")
} else {
    console.log('yes')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) :

> **Equality (==)**

> The equality operator == converts the operands if they are not of the
> same type, then applies strict comparison.

So `!placeCost` (like its more verbose form : `placeCost == false`) is evaluated to `true` if `placeCost` is the `0` number as `0` is converted to the `false` value.

You want do a strict comparison ?
Use `===` that performs no conversion :

> The identity operator returns true if the operands are strictly equal
> (see above) with no type conversion.

Comment: for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

if placeCost is 0 
then !placeCost  become 1, that will leads the condition is true.

```
if (!placeCost) // condition true when placeCost is 0
```

Comment: not a good idea, what if the placeCost is null? it will become true.