# Show default image in Angular2

Tags: html, angular, rest, typescript, spring-boot

This is what I have in my html file:

```
<img src="{{( REST_URL + userId) || this.defaultImage }}" height="200" />
```

REST_URL is user/ (on browser call http://localhost:8080/user/123456 shows user image)

in my component.ts file variables are defined as below:

```
readonly REST_URL = 'user/';
userId: number;
```

Not all users have an image and I expect default image to be shown when the user doesn't have an image but it doesn't work... any ideas?

Comment: FYI in a template everything is presumed to be part of `this` so you don't need to prepend your variable name with it.

Answer (score 3):

It should be just **`defaultImage`**

```
<img src="{{( REST_URL) || defaultImage }}" height="200" />
```

Comment: what is REST_URL

Comment: what happens when you just do thi s <img src="{{ REST_URL  + userId }}" height="200" />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159702/discussion-between-anarkie-and-sajeetharan).

Answer (score 3):

without `this` ,a clean way :

```
<img [src]="REST_URL || defaultImage" height="200" />
```

Comment: @Anarkie where's the rest of the url image `.../img.png`?

Comment: REST_URL is a rest call without /img.png

Comment: what's the content of `defaultImage` and where's the the user image ?

Answer (score 1):

showing default image in angular

```
REST_URL = `user/${this.userId}`;
this.restUrl = REST_URL || defaultImage;
<img [src]="restUrl" height="200" />
```

Comment: type of this.restUrl String?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, you don't need to specify `this` in your template when referring to the component class members. And there is another problem in your code...

You assume that, if the user image doesn't exist, the default image will be used as a result of the following expression:

```
(REST_URL + userId) || defaultImage
```

But that expression will never evaluate to `defaultImage` because `(REST_URL + userId)` is never [falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19839953/1009922). Even if the image doesn't exist, its URL is not null, undefined or empty. Therefore, the user image URL is always used.

---

**Solution 1**

If you have a flag that indicates if the user image exists or not, you can use code like this:

```
<img [src]="imageExists ? REST_URL + userId : defaultImage" height="200" />
```

**Solution 2**

Another solution is to handle the `error` event and to change the URL to the default image if the user image cannot be loaded:

```
<img [src]="imageUrl" height="200" (error)="onError()" />
```

```
private defaultImage = "http://www.yourWebSite.com/yourDefaultImage.jpg";

public imageUrl = REST_URL + this.userId;

public onError(): void {
    this.imageUrl = this.defaultImage;
}
```

You can try the code in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YbWkE9xrNOeLKGVmagfR?p=preview). After running it and seeing the "user image", you can make `userImage` incorrect in the code and see that the "default image" is displayed.