# Checking the presence of some values in an array of hashes in jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, hash

I want to check if a values of some key are not null or blank in an array or hashes

```
array = [{a:'1', b:''}, {a:'2', b:''}, {a:'3', b:null}]
```

Trying assert that all `b` are present (no blank or nil).
My current approach with jQuery

```
function checkPresence(array){
    result = false;
    $.each(array, function (i, field) {
        if(field['b'] !== '' && field['b'] !== null){
            result = true;
            return false;
        };
    });
    return result;
}
```

I believe/hope jQuery and Javascript have a better solution for it, but don't know it (yet).

Can you help?

Comment: You may go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript)

Comment: `array.every(function(e){ return (Object.keys(e).indexOf('b') > -1) && e['b'] !== null; });` https://jsfiddle.net/btwuLm8s/

Comment: So, what exactly do you want to return under what conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easily done with *array.prototype.some* :

```js
var array = [{a:'1', b:''}, {a:'2', b:''}, {a:'', b:null}];
var res = array.some(e => e.b);
console.log(res);
```

```js
var array = [{a:'1', b:''}, {a:'2', b:'something'}, {a:'', b:null}];
var res = array.some(e => e.b);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: just for those not using arrow functions

`return array.some(function(e){ if(e.value !== '') return true;  });`

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [{a:'1', b:''}, {a:'2', b:''}, {a:'3', b:null}]
array.some(item => !item.b)
// true if anything null or undefined or ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript's `foreach` function which is a function of `array`.

```
function checkPresence(array){

    array.foreach(function(element) {
        if(field['b'] === '' || field['b'] === null)
            return false;
    });

    return true;
}
```

I recommend you to check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference for more information about javascript.