# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to validate the fields. When user doesn't enter anything in the field and click on submit button, could not able to validate it.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RGOWMQBMvU45D7ApIk90?p=preview)

Please see the sample below:

```
    $scope.validateFields = function(){
            alert("Comments " + $scope.comments); //When fields are blank and click on submit, it shows undefined
              if($scope.comments === 'undefined'){
                 alert("comments are blank");//not printed
                 $scope.comments = 'undefined';
            }
            if( $scope.comments.length == 0){
              alert("comments length is zero"); //not printed
              $scope.comments = 'undefined';
            }
```

In the above sample code, when click on submit button without entering anything in the comments fields, it is not entering the if condition. I want to assign `$scope.comments='undefined'` when the comments field is blank and clicked on submit button.

Comment: line #3 should be `if($scope.comments === undefined){`  notice there are no quotes around `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code. You can initialize the $scope variable at the time of controller loading.

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$http){

      $scope.validateFields = function(){
          if($scope.comments){
             alert("comments are blank");
        }
        if( $scope.comments.length == 0){
          alert("comments length is zero");
        }
//      alert("validate"+ $scope.comments.length); 
      } 

      function init() {
        $scope.comments = '';
      }

      init();


    });
```

Check [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QYsmxhpS8csJRINLJHl6?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is you are checking if $scope.comments matches the string undefined, rather then checking if it is currently defined on the given scope.

```
if($scope.comments === undefined) {
    alert("comments are blank");//not printed
    $scope.comments = '';
}
```

Notice I just removed the quotes around undefined to achieve this. You can even use the shorthand for this which checks whether the value is falsey. You can find a full list of falsey values online but a couple of them are an empty string or undefined.

```
if(!$scope.comments) {
    alert("comments are blank");//not printed
    $scope.comments = '';
}
```

Next, you can avoid this completely by just initializing your $scope with comments like so.

```
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.comments = '';

    $scope.validateFields = function() {
        alert("Comments " + $scope.comments);
        if(!$scope.comments){
            alert("comments are blank");
        }
        else {
            alert("comments exist");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check for a null values is

```
if ( testVar !== null )
{
    // do action here
}
```

for undefined

```
if ( testVar !== undefined )
{
    // do action here
}
```

You can assign a avariable with undefined.

```
testVar = undefined;
```

Please refer to [falsey values in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript)