# Understanding JS compiling issues

Tags: javascript

Im working through a quick blackjack game to learn some basics in javascript and I don't understand why my code isn't working correctly. Clearly something I don't understand about the fundamentals of JavaScript

```
const types = [
  "1",
  "2",
  "3",
  "4",
  "5",
  "6",
  "7",
  "8",
  "9",
  "10",
  "J",
  "Q",
  "K",
  "A"
];
const suite = ["Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds"];
const draw = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
let cards = makeDeck(suite, types);
let score = 0;

//creates the card object
function Card(type, rank) {
  this.type = type;
  this.rank = rank;
}

//creates an array with every card
function makeDeck(suite, types) {
  let cards = [];
  let value = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < suite.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
      cards.push(new Card(types[j], suite[i]));
    }
  }

  return cards;
}


function determine(Card, score) {
  let test = 11;
  if (/^\d+$/.test(Card.type)) {
    test = parseInt(Card.type);
    console.log(test);
    return test;
  } else {
    if (Card.type === "J" || "Q" || "K") {
      test = 10;
      return test;
    } else {
      if (score > 11) {
        test = 2;
        return test;
      }
    }

    return test;
  }
}

function game() {
  let gameDeck = cards;
  let card1 = gameDeck[draw()];
  let card2 = gameDeck[draw()];
  let card3 = gameDeck[draw()];
  let card4 = gameDeck[draw()];
  let scorePlayer = determine(card1, score) + determine(card2, score);
  let scoreDealer = determine(card3, score) + determine(card4, score);

  console.log(scoreDealer);
  console.log(scorePlayer);
  console.log(card1, card2, card3, card4);
}


game();
```

So my concern is the determine function which seems to not work the way I intend it to. I have yet to implement a real scoring function but that shouldn't make a major difference at this point. Is there something incorrect with my usage of let and const?

Comment: In Javascript, this doesn't work the way you might hope: `if (Card.type === "J" || "Q" || "K") `. You need independent tests: `if (Card.type === "J" || Card.type === "Q" || Card.type === "K")` Another option is `if (["J", "Q", "K"].includes(Card.type)`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Card.type === "J" || "Q" || "K") {
      test = 10;
      return test;
    }
```

This block is true always, irrespective of the value of "Card.type". Because when the Card.type is not equal to "J", javascript checks for `if("Q")`  which is always true. Similarly `if("K")` is also true. All these are truthy values in Javascript.
Javascript has 7 falsy conditions, except which all other conditions are true. 
Try this code snippet in your browser console.

```
    if("Q") {
        console.log("This statement is true always")
    }
```

- Refer these two links for better understanding [All falsey values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript)
  and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy