# NodeJs Express app.get that handles both query and params

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, express, routes

I'm trying to create a REST Service. The route below will execute a stored procedure that will return json results

```
app.get('/spparam', function (req, res) {
var sql = require("mssql");

// config for your database
var id=0;
var config = {
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'hostname', 
    database: 'databasename' 
};
// connect to your database
sql.connect(config, function (err) {

    if (err) console.log(err);

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();

    if(!mylib.isEmptyObject(req.query)){
        id=req.query.id;
    }else if(!mylib.isEmptyObject(req.params)){
        id=req.params["id"];
    }
    // Executing Stored Prcoedure       
    request.input('requestid', sql.Int, id)
        .execute("Request_Get_ById").then(function(recordSet) {
            //console.dir(recordsets);
            //console.dir(err);
            res.send(recordSet);
            sql.close();
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
});
```

I want to minimise my code by creating one route that will handle both query (/spparam?id=1) and params (/spparam/:id/). Is this possible? Is there a better way to handle what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, you can do that with Express like this:

```
app.get('/spparam/:id?', function (req, res) {
  const id = req.params.id || req.query.id;
  // the rest of your function, and use id without caring about whether
  // it came from params or query
  // change order if you want to give preference to query
}
```

The [Express.js docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) say it uses [path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) for route matching purposes. There you can see this quote:

> Parameters can be suffixed with a question mark (?) to make the
>   parameter optional.

In javascript, the construct `var a = b || c` assigns the value of `b` to `a` if `b` is not [false-y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript), and otherwise it assigns the value of `c` to `a`.