# Why props are undefined even while I render component conditionally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, undefined

Trying to render Footer component using inline if-else to avoid passing undefined data from Firebase, somehow it is passing those props, and Footer component yelling about undefined props.

```
this.state = {
  location: {},
  hours: {}
};

componentDidMount() {
  db.collection('location').get().then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      this.setState({
        location: { ...doc.data()
        }
      })
    })
  });

  db.collection('hours').get().then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      this.setState({
        hours: { ...doc.data()
        }
      })
    })
  });
}

render({
    {
      (this.state.hours) ? < Footer hours = {
        this.state.hours
      }
      location = {
        this.state.location
      }
      /> : null }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are initializing this.state.hours to the empty object {}

An empty object will evaluate to true in Javascript

```
if ({}) console.log("yes"); // Prints "yes"
```

Perhaps you should initialize it to false instead

```
this.state={
  location: {},
  hours: false
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The way your code is now, `this.state.hours` will never be falsey. An empty object is truthy.
See [All falsey values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript) for more details.

You either need a separate boolean in state letting you know whether or not `hours` has been loaded or you need to check for something more specific within `this.state.hours`. Another option would be to initialize `this.state.hours` to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't check state like this `(this.state.hours)?` it will be false when `this.state.hours` is `0` or `''`, but it will be true when `this.state.hours` is `{}`.
Try using `null` instead, with condition `== null` (to check if `null` or `undefined`) or `=== null` to check if `null`:

```
this.state={
  location: {},
  hours: null
};

 componentDidMount(){
 db.collection('location').get().then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    this.setState({
      location: {...doc.data()}
    })
  })
});

db.collection('hours').get().then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    this.setState({
      hours: {...doc.data()}
    })
  })
});
}

render({
  {(this.state.hours === null)? <Footer hours={this.state.hours} location={this.state.location}/> : null }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just change the render code to check if the location object has key. like this

```
render({
  {(Object.keys(this.state.hours).length <= 0)? <Footer hours={this.state.hours} location={this.state.location}/> : null }
})
```