# How to gid rid of some properties from an object based on condition?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an object and I want to remove all properties that have a value of `null`, but I want to keep a special property which is `alwaysCountWithMe` (even if its value is null). My code looks like this:

```
var object = {
"firstname": null, 
"lastname": "White", 
"hobby": null,
"c": 3 , 
"alwaysCountWithMe": null
};
console.log(_.pickBy(object, value => !!value));
```

This prints:

> ```
> {"lastname": "White", "c": 3}
> ```

But I want it to print:

> ```
> {"lastname": "White", "c": 3, "alwaysCountWithMe": null }
> ```

Comment: I’m guessing you’re using lodash? If it’s underscore, please replace the tag

Comment: Yes, I'm using lodash, what would be your solution to this?

Comment: It should be noted that `!!value` will also drop properties with any [falsey value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19839953/1813169). Use `value !== null` to explicitly detect nulls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the second argument passed to the pickBy method is the key name, so you could probably change it to:

```
console.log(_.pickBy(object, (value, key) => !!value || key === 'alwaysCountWithMe'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on your existing solution, how about this using some new ES6 object syntax:

```js
var object = { firstname: null, lastname: 'White', hobby: null, c: 3, alwaysCountWithMe: null };
console.log({
  ...(_.pickBy(object, value => value !== null)),
  alwaysCountWithMe: object.alwaysCountWithMe
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your function (the second argument of `_.pickBy`) to take the `key` argument so you can check if `key` is `alwaysCountWithMe`:

```js
var object = {
  "firstname": null,
  "lastname": "White",
  "hobby": null,
  "c": 3,
  "alwaysCountWithMe": null
};

    console.log(_.pickBy(object, (value, key) => !!value || key == "alwaysCountWithMe"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```