# DailyCodingProblem, find pair in array that matches a given value

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to coding and enlisted for the daily coding problem mailing list and got this question:

> Given a list of numbers and a number k, return whether any two numbers
>   from the list add up to k.

My solution (after some stackoverflow digging) looks like this;

```
function problemOne_Solve()
{
    const k = 17;
    const values = [11, 15, 3, 8, 2];
    for (i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if ( values.find( (sum) => { return k-values[i] === sum} ) ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm wondering why it works. To me it looks like the part with the fat-arrow function closes the brackets inside the if statements conditional logic. And there is no such brackets after the if statement, which I thought was required.

I was also wondering how i would go about outputting the pair or pairs that sums up to "k," to build further on the solution. I would like to be able to display the pairs on the page for example.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: if that is your solution, and you don't understand it, is it really *your* solution?

Comment: _“To me it looks like the part with the fat-arrow function closes the brackets inside the if statements conditional logic.”_ - `values.find( (sum) => { return k-values[i] === sum} )` in its entirety is the _condition_ of this `if` statement. _“And there is no such brackets after the if statement, which i thought was required.”_ - they aren’t. You can use them to create a _block_; if you don’t use them, then only the first expression directly following the `if` will be dependent on it. You should really go read up on this stuff somewhere, this is pretty basic knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.find` takes a callback, which is invoked for every item in the array (or, up until a match is found). The first argument to the callback is the item being iterated over. If a match is found (if the return value from the callback was truthy for any element), the `.find` returns the item that resulted in a truthy return value.

So, on the first `i = 0` iteration, and `values[i]` is `11`, `(sum) => { return k-values[i] === sum}` will first check whether `17 - 11 === 11`, and then whether `17 - 11 === 15`, and then whether `17 - 11 = 3`, etc.

This condition will generally be fulfilled if two numbers in the array add up to the `k`, but the algorithm is buggy. For example, an array composed of `[1]` will check the 1 against itself on the first iteration, adding up to 2:

```js
function problemOne_Solve() {
    const k = 2;
    const values = [1];
    for (i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if ( values.find( (sum) => { return k-values[i] === sum} ) ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(problemOne_Solve());
```

That is wrong. Another problem is that `.find` returns the found value. But, if the array is an array of numbers, the found value may be 0, and 0 is falsey. So the below example should return `true` because two elements sum up to 0 (0 and 0), but it returns `false`:

```js
function problemOne_Solve() {
    const k = 0;
    const values = [0, 0];
    for (i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if ( values.find( (sum) => { return k-values[i] === sum} ) ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(problemOne_Solve());
```

To get it right *and* decrease the computational complexity from `O(n ^ 2)` to `O(n)`, iterate over the array *once*. Create an object whose keys are the numbers being iterated over, and on each iteration, check to see if a key of `target - currNum` exists on the object (where `target` is the target sum, and `currNum` is the current number from the array):

```js
function problemOne_Solve() {
  const target = 17;
  const values = [11, 15, 3, 8, 2];
  const obj = {};
  for (const currNum of values) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(target - currNum)) {
      return true;
    }
    obj[currNum] = true;
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(problemOne_Solve());
```

> I was also wondering how i would go about outputting the pair or pairs that sums up to "k," to build further on the solution. I would like to be able to display the pairs on the page for example.

Instead of returning immediately when a match is found, push to an array and then return that array at the end of the function. Also, instead of setting the object values to `true` (or `false`), set them to the number of occurrences the number has been found so far (and decrement the matching number when a match is found):

```js
function problemOne_Solve() {
  const target = 17;
  const values = [11, 15, 3, 8, 2, 17, 0, 0, 17];
  const obj = {};
  const matches = [];
  for (const currNum of values) {
    const otherNum = target - currNum;
    if (obj[otherNum]) {
      obj[otherNum]--;
      matches.push([currNum, otherNum]);
    }
    obj[currNum] = (obj[currNum] || 0) + 1;
  }
  return matches;
}
console.log(problemOne_Solve());
```

> And there is no such brackets after the if statement, which I thought was required.

Brackets are not required when there's a single statement after an `if` (or `else if` or `else`), eg:

```js
if (true) console.log('true');
else console.log('this will not log');
```

Answer (score 0):

> And there is no such brackets after the if statement, which I thought was required.

If there is only one statement after `if` `else` the brackets becomes optional. Ideally you shouldn't write the `if` block is one line to make your code clean

As you are a beginner I would recommend you to use simple `for` loops instead of these fancy methods like `find`.

You can do that in following steps:

- Its clear that you need sum of each element with every other element of array. So you will need a nested loop structure
- The outer loop or main loop starts from `0` and loop till end of array.
- You need to create a inner loop or nested loop which starts from index after the current index.
- In the each iteration of nested loop you need to check if the sum of two elements is equal to `requiredSum` or not.

```js
function pairWithSum(givenArray, requiredSum){
  for(let i = 0; i < givenArray.length; i++){
    for(let j = i + 1; j < givenArray.length; j++){
      let sum = givenArray[i] + givenArray[j];
      if(sum === requiredSum){
        return [givenArray[i], givenArray[j]];
      }
    }
  }
  return false
}

console.log(pairWithSum([1, 4, 5, 8], 12));
console.log(pairWithSum([1, 4, 5, 8], 15));
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering why it works

That is because, `if` expects an expression/ statement to validate.

```
values.find( (sum) => { return k-values[i] === sum} )
```

This is a statement and it will be evaluated before and its output will be passed to `if` for condition.

Now `Array.find` has a return type: `T|<null>` where `T` is any value array is made of. So in second iteration, when `values[i]` refers to *15*, it will return *2*.

Now in JS, `2` is a truthy value and hence it goes inside `if` block. Foe more reference, check [All falsey values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript). Any value that is not in this list will be considered as true.

Answer (score 0):

My Javascript solution using JS object. This solution memories the elements when we go through the array which can be memory expensive. But the complexity will stay as O(n).

```
const checkTwoSum = (arr, sum) => {
  const obj = {};
  const found = arr?.find(item => {
    const target = sum - item;
    if (obj[target]) return true;
    else {
        obj[item] = 1;
    }
  });

  return !!(found || found === 0);
}
```