# Javascript difference between if(id != null) vs if(!id)

Tags: javascript

I understand strict type comparison with '===' and '!==' checking if the value and type are equal.

Comparing with '==' or '!=' will cast the variable to the value to be compared. So for example comparing a variable 'id' with null will cast 'id' value, meaning 0, '', null, undefined equals null.

I would like to know if the following two ways of writing a condition are really completely the same:

```
if (id != null) {}
```

and on the other hand

```
if (!id) {}
```

Comment: what happens if `var id = 1;`?

Comment: You can use `if (!x)` to check any falsy value, but it doesn't work reversed, for example `0 == null` is false.

Comment: *"0, '', null, undefined equals null"* is incorrect. Only `undefined` and `null` satisfy the `x == null` loose comparison. `id != null` -> Everything except undefined and null. `!id` -> Everything except [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values (0, null, undefined, '', NaN etc)

Comment: This might help: [All falsey (and truthy) values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript)