# How to check for null or undefined number but handle the zero value?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
@Input() a: number;

// Check of null or undefined
if (a)
  // do stuff
```

With the usual check, the value 0 will also be considered as false and the variable will not pass the if.

There is already a lot of questions around this but I could not find anything that handles the value zero.
Is there anything like the `a?.b` of typescript but for simple type?

Comment: null || undefined check?

Comment: `a === undefined || a === null`? Or `a == null` or `a == undefined` but I prefer strict equality for explicitness...

Comment: You could use `if (a ?? false)` but that's just confusing and harder to digest.

Comment: Checking both works but is quite verbose... I was hoping for a simpler solution

Comment: Input() a: number = null, or in the if  if(!!a)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is the verbose (when you need to check multiple values it quickly becomes crowded in your condition).

```
if (a !== undefined && a !== null)
  // do stuff
```

I also thought of this, a bit shorter but less obvious to read

```
if (a || a === 0)
  // do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the code from becoming crowded is a good goal. You can define your own functions, like so:

```
function isBlank(s) {
    return (undefined === s || null === s || "" == s.trim());
}
function isZero(s) {
    return (!isBlank(s) && "0" == s.trim());
}
```

Your original code block changes as follows, and is just as easy to read:

```
// Check of null or undefined
if (isZero(a))
  // do stuff
```

For more information on the falsy values in JavaScript, here are a few good resources:

https://stackabuse.com/javascript-loose-equality-operator-vs-strict-equality-operator/

[All falsey values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript)

---

To play around with some additional values:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lr98kzsa/