# Checking if a variable is anything other than 0/false/null etc. using the == operator?

Tags: javascript, variables

```
function test(variable, check) {

    var check = check || ???;

    if (variable == check) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

I want this function to check if the variable is anything that `if(variable) return true;` would return true, any number greater than 0 for example. I'd like to keep this simple formatting and use the `==` operator for when `check` is a specific value if possible, so what could I default it to in order to achieve this?

I could achieve the same thing with this code:

```
function test(variable, check) {

    if(check) {

        //check specific value
        if (variable == check) {
            //do stuff
        }

    } else {

        //check isn't set, so accept any truthy values (like 5 or 'string')
        if(variable) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @LoïsDiQual but `5 == false` would return false too.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982663/falsey-values-in-javascript

Comment: @MrAdam nope, this will alert(5||false); popup 5

Comment: @Joraid Well of course, but if I use `var check = check || false` as suggested then the variable will be checked against `false` if check isn't set, so if the variable is 5 then it's going to return false when my goal is for it to return true.

Comment: So, if the input is `false`, `0`, `""`, `undefined` or `null`, `variable == check` should always be considered truthy, right?

Comment: @wared The variable will always be something that `if(variable)` would return true, such as numbers > 0, I basically want to achieve the exact same thing as `if(variable)` but with the `==` operator for simplicity's sake, so the function can check if the input is a specific value OR any value that `if(variable)` would return true. I could just repeat the code in an if statement to check if `check` is set or not, but I wanted to see if I could keep it simple. Perhaps it isn't possible without more code.

Comment: @wared There we go. I don't want to return anything, it's just a check. I might end up having to do it the second way (or a variation of the second way), I was just wondering if I could keep it as simple as the first way.

Comment: If `check` is set, regardless if it's truthy or falsy, compare with `variable`, otherwise, `variable` must be truthy, right?

Comment: Or, if `check` is truthy, compare with `variable`, otherwise, `variable` must be truthy?

Comment: @wared `check` will always be truthy if it's set. So if it is set, it must equal `variable`, if `check` isn't set then `variable` must be truthy. Basically what you said except `check` will always be truthy if set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After chatting a little, here is the answer :

```
if (check ? check == variable : variable) {
    // do something
}
```

That was obvious actually... =D

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I kicked myself.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you would like to basically return `if(variable) true`, as well as check to see if it equals the second parameter? If so, this should suffice:

```
function test(variable, check) {
  if(variable == check) return true; //check against the check value
  if(variable) return true; //default check
  return false; //return false otherwise.
}
```

Comment: `if(variable)return true;return false;` could be `return !!variable;`.

Comment: Even shorter : `return variable == check || !!variable;`.

Comment: @wared true, but for simplicity, this should be easier to understand. perhaps you should post that as an alternate answer

Comment: A comment is enough since the code does exactly the same as yours. I agree though, your code is easier to understand.