# Is it possible to do "if .. || if .."?

Tags: javascript, syntax, operator-keyword

I had a question regarding the || operator in javascript. To my understanding it can be used as either an 'OR' operator, or a null coalescing operator.

My question is, can I use if statements in conjunction with the || null coalescing operator? For example,

```
if (x=y){
alert("Yup");
}||if (x=0){
alert("Nope);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope, but you can use `else if `

Comment: `||` is *not* a "null coalescing" operator. It is a lazily-evaluated Boolean-OR operator. (Anyway, Statements - such as `if` - *cannot* be used as Expressions.)

Answer (score 4):

No.  Just use `else`

The JavaScript grammar distinguishes between statements like

```
if (condition) statement else statement
```

and expressions like

```
expr || expr
```

A statement can contain expressions with few restrictions<sup>°</sup> via the `ExpressionStatement` production, but expressions can only contain statements in a very limited way<sup>°°</sup>.

So

```
{statement} || {statement}
```

is neither a valid statement nor a valid expression because the JavaScript parser sees the `||` where it expects a statement to appear and reports a parse error.

---

Second, `||` is not really "null-coalescing".  To see why, consider

```
alert(false || null)  // alerts "null" not "false"
alert(0     || null)  // alerts "null" not "0"
alert(""    || null)  // alerts "null" not the empty string
alert((0/0) || null)  // alerts "null" not "NaN"
```

Since the left-hand-sides of the `||` are [*falsey*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982663/falsey-values-in-javascript) the `null` is given preference which is not what you would expect if only nulls were coalesced.

---

° - the `{ key: value }` object constructor is ambiguous with blocks, and named function expressions are ambiguous with function declarations so both are banned unless parenthesized.

°° - a function expression like `function () { ... }` can contain statements in its body.